# How can I install and use website using drupal8 composer?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-8

I tried to run inststruction from the official website but I cannot understand why I cannot access my website and what do I need to fix? 
My website is in the directory /var/www/drupal8.
The files are as follows: [image]

I installed it using composer from here https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229

What do I need to do next? I want to access my website in the browser as I can in Drupal 7 just typing my local website name, for example drupal7.loc

Answer (score 1):

Configure your VirtualHost entry to point to `drupal8/web`. The actual Drupal root directory is the `web` directory. That's where the index.php file, etc. are.

Also, your screenshot doesn't show it, but make sure you have a `drupal8/web/core` directory. It should be there if you ran the `composer create-project` command, but if not, you'll need to run `composer install` in the project root (`/drupal8`) before your site will load.